# Android child onTouchListener disabling parent onClick

Tags: android, event-handling, parent-child, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have a parent, custom RelativeLayout which inflates two ImageViews: one content image, and a close button in the top right corner.

The issue: I cannot have both the gestures/scaling of the content image functioning AND the close button functioning.

The content image is a custom ImageView subclass (a modification of https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView), which has it's own OnTouchListener to allow for pinch-zooming, and responding to usual gestures. 
This OnTouchListener contains the code:

```
private class PrivateOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        //....
        return true;
```

Now, if that return is true, the scaling/gestures for the content image works, but the close button onClick is never called, whereas if it's false then the scaling/getures don't work and the onClick can be called.

I don't understand why a return function called AFTER the event is passed to the gesture detector affects (?consumes the event) whether or not the gesture detector works. 
Is there a simple way of ensuring the functionality of both child ImageViews, where that return function is false but both detectors still work?

What I've tried:

- Ensuring all methods in the gestureDetector return false, so that the event isn't consumed. (The scaleDetector isn't custom, so I haven't done the same there; if you think that's where the problem is let me know)
- An onInterceptTouch method in the parent RelativeLayout, but I'm not sure if I implemented that correctly
- (Reading around event handling to understand how it works)